# JPA @PreUpdate not called on all entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an `@MappedSuperclass` that contains metadata stuff like creation and last modified date. All my entities extend this class. The class also has a method annotated with `@PreUpdate` that set these properties before the according action.

What is currently driving me crazy is that this work for entity A and C but not for B. They all extend this `BaseEntity` directly. Basically there is 0 reason they should behave differently. Even more confusing is that `@PrePresist` is called correctly on all of the entities, also B.

Anyone has an idea why this happens? It's driving me nuts...

```
public class A extends BaseEntity {}

public class B extends BaseEntity {}

public class C extends BaseEntity {}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Getter
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created")
    private Date created;

    @Getter
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    private Date lastModified;

    @Getter
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Getter
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by")
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @PreUpdate
    public final void updateMetadata() {
        lastModified = new Date();
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            lastModifiedBy = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getName();
        }
    }

    @PrePersist
    public final void createMetadata() {
        created = new Date();
        lastModified = created;
        if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
            final String userName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                    .getAuthentication().getName();
            lastModifiedBy = userName;
            createdBy = userName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is nothing to see there...thats the point

Comment: which version of hibernate?

Comment: the code shows nothing to explain the issue. are you also calling persist() or only merge()? what do the subclasses look like? can you post some code where you actually access the entity manager?

Comment: I use spring-data. Spring data abstracts this in the save() method but internally calls persist if id == null else merge.

Comment: well, it's difficult to guess what's wrong here. Have you debugged the code to be sure that PreUpdate really is not called for B? There must be a difference between A,B and C that is significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys the issue is as follows:

The tests run using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. The issue is that the test for entity B is annotated with `@Transactional`. This means that `@PreUpdate` is only called after the test completes and hence the test fails.

The behavior is the same for all entities if they are all annotated in the same way regarding `@Transactional`.

For `@PrePersist` it seems this is called instantly even before the transaction completes and hence no issue there.

Comment: Call flush to have it executed within the test

Comment: BTW, I think you should not have your tests create a different "execution context" for the code that is tested, as long as it's not very difficult to avoid.

Comment: i use `@Transactional` together with `Rollback(true)` so that any changes to the data store are reverted because else others tests might fail.